# Negative value for Foreign Key in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, relational-database

I will be creating a request with approval workflow database but then i am having a second thought of having a negative value in a Foreign Column which is specifically when assigning on to whom should it be assigned. I'm about to set it as Positive Value (> 0) if it is assigned to a specific user or make it negative (< 0) if it was assigned to a group or cluster.

Can someone who worked with these kind of databases give some thoughts on what i'm about to do if it is fine or not and why?

[image]
I am trying to merge assigned_to_id with assigned_to_cluster_id by setting it as negative which will be the absolute value of cluster_id. Only if it is assigned to a cluster

Comment: Could you please provide a bit more information on the structure, what the data is, and it will be used?

Comment: As you were having trouble with the description, i've added an image. Thanks!

Comment: maybe if you would show some sample data for each table it would be more clear to us what you mean

Comment: You cannot just enter any value in a FK field, the value you enter (negative or not) MUST exist in the referenced table.

Comment: Yes of course. That is why it is called FK (Foreign Key) it means i am referencing to User / Cluster table as mentioned in the description and the data type is integer since i mentioned "Negative".

Comment: why dont you show some sample data, for this table and for the referenced tables. As it is your question is hard to understand what you are trying to achive

Comment: In case you are thinking of using ONE column as FK that references 2 tables, than DONT. Its not even possible, not in sql server and I am pretty sure no database allows that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the idea you want to use just one column for `assigned_to_id` and `assigned_to_cluster_id`

So when its a negative value it would point to a row in `table A`, and when positive it would point to a row in `table B`

If that is the case, dont do it.
This is not possible in a relational database, if that is what you want then you cannot mark it as Foreign Key and you would have to invent the wheel all over again and do all the work yourself that the database is doing for you now

This would mean dropping the foreign key constraints, and thus dropping relational integrity

And lots of extra coding to be done by you

What are you trying to achieve anyway by doing this ?

Keep both columns, keep them as foreign key fields, just write a case in you select statements if that is the problem

```
select rw.ID,
       ...,
       case when rw.assigned_to_id is not null then a.name
            when rw.assigned_to_cluster_id is not null then b.name
            else 'not assigned'
       end as assigned_to
from   request_workflow rw
  left outer join tableA a on rw.assigned_to_id = a.id
  left outer join tableB b on rw.assigned_to_cluster_id = b.id
```

Comment: Thank you for reminding me the rule of relating a table. I just created another table now which contains all the assigned user. So when a cluster will be assigned, i will put all the members in that table instead and referencing to the main table. Thanks!